# Git call SSH with keys not working

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have cloned to a local folder (located on my windows 7 PC) the git repository of my website (hosted on a CentOS 7 server). I want to use git commands like `git pull` without having to enter the password of the user each time.

```
>git remote -v
origin  ssh://mylinuxuser@1.2.3.4:1234/home/mylinuxuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/ (fetch)
origin  ssh://mylinuxuser@1.2.3.4:1234/home/mylinuxuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/ (push)
```

I have created a key pair. The `id_rsa` file is in `C:\Users\mywindowsuser\.ssh` and the `id_rsa.pub` I have sent to the server and added to the `authorized_keys` file :

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

The `authorized_keys` file is owned by `mylinuxuser` and access rights are `600`. Access rights of the `.ssh` folder are `700`.

On my local machine, I have filled the `config` file in the `.ssh` folder with

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

i tried to restart ssh `service sshd restart` as `su` on the linux server as well. Didn't help.

Also added `id_rsa` to many paths because  Ifound some answers leading this way on stack :

```
C:\Program Files\Git\.ssh
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh
C:\Users\mywindowsuser\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Git\.ssh
C:\Users\mywindowsuser\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh
```

None of these worked. I wonder if any other file is interfering. For example, I have an `environment` file and a `known_hosts` file in `C:\Users\mywindowsuser\.ssh` but I doubt it.

Still, anytime I try and call `git pull` it asks for `mylinuxuser` password...

Any help would be appreciated !

[EDIT] result of the suggestion in the comments :

```
ssh -v -p1234 mylinuxuser@1.2.3.4
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/mywindowsuser/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/mywindowsuser/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 1.2.3.4 [1.2.3.4] port 1234.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mywindowsuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mywindowsuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 1.2.3.4:1234 as 'mylinuxuser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-128-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-128-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:verylongkey
debug1: Host '[1.2.3.4]:1234' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/mywindowsuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/mywindowsuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: I'm assuming you added the public ssh key to the git-hub account but you may need to add your new private key to the ssh-agent.  Try `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.  Make sure the `ssh-agent` is running.

Comment: It's not a github account as I said it's a private server. I did what you suggested - in regular cmd it didn't work but it did in git bash and I got `Identity added: /c/Users/mywindowsuser/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/mywindowsuser/.ssh/id_rsa)` as an answer... But it still asks for password when I try `git pull` so it didn't work, sadly

Comment: Debug it by trying to log in with ssh verbosely. `ssh -v -v -p 1234 mylinuxuser@1.2.3.4`

Comment: @Schwern edited with data from the verbose call

Comment: The key is being offered, but rejected. Double check that `authorized_keys` is in `~mylinuxuser/.ssh` on the remote and that `authorized_keys` contains your public key on its own line; if `authorized_keys` didn't have a newline on the end then `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys` would leave it malformed.

Comment: -_- I was going to say yes, of course, but you know what ? I checked again and well... It was on a new line as I thought BUT something happened and `ssh-rsa` was on its own line and the rest of the key on another one ! Thanks, really

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem what your facing.

You need to provide the access rights.

Try chmod 600, it will resolve your problem.

```
chmod 700/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh
```

Above thing solves your problem, then you don't need to follow this.
make sure other user not able to modify your dir.

```
chmod g-w,o-w /home/USERNAME
```

Comment: The implication here is you're allowing remote login as root. Don't encourage people to login as root, it's like walking around holding a loaded gun, safety off, finger on the trigger. Have them use sudo.

Comment: @Schwern, you're right, it's not encourageable to login as root.